# How do I blastp multiple fasta files, and move the files with say 50 to 90% similarity to another folder?

Tags: file-comparison, bioinformatics

So I have about 100 fasta files to blast and I need to find files with 50 to 90% similarities with the database file. Then the files are to be moved to a new folder. How do I do this?

Comment: This isn't a site dedicated to bioinformatics. Most people here will have no idea what fasta files are, nor what blastp is. Please [edit] your question and explain so that non bioinformaticians will understand. Show an example of your files, an example of the blastp output (which can have different formats, by the way, so even bioinformaticians need to see it) Are your FASTA files one sequence per file? Is the name of the file the name of the sequence? Do you have one sequence in the database or many?

Comment: You should consider posting it in biostars website